# scala abusive implicit conversion

Tags: scala, overriding, implicit-conversion

In scala 2.10 REPFL:

```
>
class E(val i: Int) { def += (other: E) = i - other.i }
implicit def toE(i: Int) = new E(i)
var j = 1
j += 3
```

Results in:

```
res1: Int = -2
> j
j: Int = 1
```

Note that there is no interference with the regular `+=` if the class E itself is marked as implicit, compared to using the previous conversion method.

Wow, I have been able to completely wreak havoc a program if this implicit conversion is in scope ! Is there a way to ask scala not to convert to implicits if a meaning already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot answer if this behavior can be changed, but I have found the following description in the specification (p. 85):

> Assignment operators are treated specially in that they can be
>   expanded to assignments **if no other interpretation is valid**. Let’s
>   consider an assignment operator such as += in an inﬁx operation l +=
>   r, where l, r are expressions. This operation can be re-interpreted as
>   an operation which corresponds to the assignment l = l + r

From this I understand that because you have provided an alternative interpretation, the expansion does not take place. Myabe it will be helpful in tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer didn't quote the entire passage from the spec, which is explicit:

> The re-interpretation occurs if the following two conditions are
>   fulfilled.
>   1. The left-hand-side l does not have a member named +=, and also cannot be converted by an implicit conversion (§6.26) to a value with
>   a member named
>   +=.

(The other condition is that it typechecks.)

When you make the class also implicit, you have defined two implicit conversions (one of which is your `toE`) which are ambiguous and silently ignored. (That is a feature of sorts.)

So you've answered your own question: one way to turn off an implicit is to make it ambiguous.

The other way is to shadow the name, since the implicit must be available by its simple name.

On wreaking havoc: now you know why you have to `import scala.language.implicitConversions`.

I guess you also know now what the F--- in REPFL [sic] stands for.